# How to show Image when No internet connection in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am Beginner in Ionic 2 . I am working on **Network Connection/Detection**  Using Network native plugin. 
I want show **wifi symbol image** when there is **no Internet connection** 
Example . [image]

And i want to hide this Dashboard when there is no internet connection and required to show **wifi image symbol** like above image

[image]

This is my code for **dashboard.html**

```
<ion-grid responsive-sm  center >
        <ion-row style="background-color: #fff;">
           </ion-row>
     <ion-row  center>
        <ion-col  (click)="gotomaps()">  <ion-fab  >
            <button ion-fab  >  <img  src="assets/icon/location.png"/>  </button>
            <ion-grid text-center> 
            <label  style="font-size: 15px; font-family:inherit; text-align:center ;margin:8px;color:#A62C23;font-weight: bold"> Mapping</label>
          </ion-grid>
          </ion-fab> 
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col width-50  center (click)="gotosendmanager()"> <ion-fab  >
            <button ion-fab  > <img  src="assets/icon/folder.png"/> </button>
            <ion-grid text-center> 
            <label style="font-size: 15px; font-family: arial; text-align:center;margin:8px;color:#A62C23;font-weight: bold"> Send manager</label>
          </ion-grid>
          </ion-fab> 
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <div class="or-label" text-center hidden>
          <img alt="Logo"  src="assets/imgs/wifi.png" >
      </div>  

      <ion-row >
          <ion-col width-50 (click)="gototabs()"> <ion-fab  >
              <button ion-fab  > <img  src="assets/icon/question.png"/> </button>
              <ion-grid text-center> 
              <label style="font-size: 15px; font-family: arial; text-align:center ;margin:8px;color:#A62C23;font-weight: bold"> Help</label>
            </ion-grid>
            </ion-fab> 
          </ion-col>

          <ion-col width-50 (click)="exit()"> <ion-fab  >
              <button ion-fab  > <img  src="assets/icon/logout.png"/> </button>
              <ion-grid text-center> 
              <label style="font-size: 15px; font-family: arial; text-align:center ;margin:8px;color:#A62C23;font-weight: bold"> Exit</label>
            </ion-grid>
            </ion-fab> 
          </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row style="background-color: #fff;">



      </ion-row>

    </ion-grid>
```

Comment: i am waiting for your response....

Comment: What is this @Harshal Deshmukh firstly you accept then you remove it ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have get perfect image **hide and show w.r.to Internet connection** with this code

**Import Network plugin**

import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';

**Put this under before constructor**

```
hide:boolean = true;
```

**Put this code under Constructor**

```
var offline = Observable.fromEvent(document, "offline");
    var online = Observable.fromEvent(document, "online");

    offline.subscribe(() => {
      this.hide =false;

    });

    online.subscribe(()=>{
      this.hide =true;

    });
```

**Put this under html file**

```
<div class="or-label" text-center *ngIf="!hide" >
          <img alt="Logo"  src="assets/imgs/wifi.png" >
      </div>
```

//**Result :**  When your device Internet is not available then wifi image is visible and wise versa..

Comment: @harsal you are not use Network library for online offline event. Are it needed or not

Answer (score 2):

**I will create for you`NetworkConnectionProvider.ts` provider for listening network event.**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform, ToastController, Events} from "ionic-angular";
import {Network} from "@ionic-native/network";

export enum ConnectionStatusEnum {
  Online,
  Offline
}

@Injectable()
export class NetworkConnectionProvider {

  public isOnline: boolean = true;
  private previousStatus;
  constructor(private network: Network,
              private  platform:Platform,
              private toastCtrl: ToastController,
              private eventCtrl: Events) {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
      this.initializeNetworkEvents();
    });

  }

  public initializeNetworkEvents(): void {

    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.previousStatus === ConnectionStatusEnum.Online) {
        this.eventCtrl.publish('network:offline');

      }
      this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline;
      this.isOnline = false;
    });

    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.previousStatus === ConnectionStatusEnum.Offline) {
        this.eventCtrl.publish('network:online');

      }
      this.previousStatus = ConnectionStatusEnum.Online;
      this.isOnline = true;
    });
  }

}
```

**And then inject in `NetworkConnectionProvider` in `app.module.ts`**

**Provider Uses**
**In `dashboard.ts`**

First of all inject `private networkCheck:NetworkConnectionProvider` and  `private eventCtrl: Events` in `constructor`. Then listen it.

```
 flag:boolean=false;

  this.eventCtrl.subscribe('network:online', () => {
    // online action 
    this.flag =true;
  });

  this.eventCtrl.subscribe('network:offline', () => {
   // offline action 
   this.flag =false;
  });
```

**In `dashboard.html` need to modify**

```
<ion-grid responsive-sm  center >
        <ion-row style="background-color: #fff;">
           </ion-row>
     <ion-row  center *ngIf="flag">
        <ion-col  (click)="gotomaps()">  <ion-fab  >
            <button ion-fab  >  <img  src="assets/icon/location.png"/>  </button>
            <ion-grid text-center> 
            <label  style="font-size: 15px; font-family:inherit; text-align:center ;margin:8px;color:#A62C23;font-weight: bold"> Mapping</label>
          </ion-grid>
          </ion-fab> 
        </ion-col>

        <ion-col width-50  center (click)="gotosendmanager()"> <ion-fab  >
            <button ion-fab  > <img  src="assets/icon/folder.png"/> </button>
            <ion-grid text-center> 
            <label style="font-size: 15px; font-family: arial; text-align:center;margin:8px;color:#A62C23;font-weight: bold"> Send manager</label>
          </ion-grid>
          </ion-fab> 
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <div class="or-label" text-center *ngIf="!flag">
          <img alt="Logo"  src="assets/imgs/wifi.png" >
      </div>  

      <ion-row *ngIf="flag">
          <ion-col width-50 (click)="gototabs()"> <ion-fab  >
              <button ion-fab  > <img  src="assets/icon/question.png"/> </button>
              <ion-grid text-center> 
              <label style="font-size: 15px; font-family: arial; text-align:center ;margin:8px;color:#A62C23;font-weight: bold"> Help</label>
            </ion-grid>
            </ion-fab> 
          </ion-col>

          <ion-col width-50 (click)="exit()"> <ion-fab  >
              <button ion-fab  > <img  src="assets/icon/logout.png"/> </button>
              <ion-grid text-center> 
              <label style="font-size: 15px; font-family: arial; text-align:center ;margin:8px;color:#A62C23;font-weight: bold"> Exit</label>
            </ion-grid>
            </ion-fab> 
          </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

      <ion-row style="background-color: #fff;">



      </ion-row>

    </ion-grid>
```

Comment: Sir i want to hide ion-grid when network is not available and show wifi image . How to hide that one, this i am not understand ?

Comment: <div class="or-label" text-center hidden>
          <img alt="Logo"  src="assets/imgs/wifi.png" >
      </div>  this is my image div ..I am really thankful for  you for this your answer

Comment: <div class="or-label" text-center *ngIf="!flag"> <img alt="Logo" src="assets/imgs/wifi.png" > </div>
a

Comment: check it @HarshalDeshmukh

Comment: yes working on this but i am not getting proper result when i am set to connection off ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167165/discussion-between-utpaul-and-harshal-deshmukh).

Comment: accept my answer too . I have done in direct way without creating Provider.ts @Utpaul

Answer (score 0):

Following @Utpaul answer. You can also use hidden attribute which doesn't delete your element from the Dom like ngIf does.

```
<ion-grid responsive-sm  center [hidden]="flag" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this concept can help you..

You can use @ionic-native/network

To check current network connection inside the device

```
isConnected(): boolean {
    let conntype = this.network.type;
    return conntype && conntype !== 'unknown' && conntype !== 'none';
}
```

There is a function like `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` inside the `ionic-native/network` modules, but it only checks whenever you connect/disconnect the network from your phone when you were in-app. and maybe its useful to use the function if someone suddenly has no /disable the network connection

Constructor :

```
constructor(private network: Network, private toast: ToastController) { }
```

Simply put in the constructor

```
if(!this.isConnected()) {
    this.openToast(this.isConnected());
}
```

Simply put inside the constructor of the page, This is how we can automatically check the network connection after the page is loaded

openToast() function

```
openToast(isConnected: boolean) {
    let networkType = this.network.type;
    this.toast.create({
      message: `Network type: ${networkType} and ${isConnected}`,
      duration: 3000
    }).present();
}
```

and take note that in ionic 3.. The supported version of `@ionic-native/network` < 5.0.0

I tested on Ionic 3 can use version 4.6.0

This is how we declare `import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/index';`

More info :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/network

> Result : if the user open up the page with no internet connection,
>   it's toast up a message

I hope someone found this helpful information